# Change the title to all titles in string

Tags: preg-match-all

I would like to change the titles of each title found in string.

e.g. using the following string

```
$newText = ' title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg"  title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg"  title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg" ';
```

I need to perform a preg_match_all so to find all the instances and then for each one, search the database for new title and then substitute.

Here is what I have done allready:

```
$newText = ' title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg"  title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg"  title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg" ';

if ($matches2 = preg_match_all('/.?title2="(.*?)"/', $newText, $repeat2, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {

$replace2 = ' title="'.$title.'"';

for ($x2 = 0; $x2 < $matches2; $x2++) {

    $value = $repeat2[1][$x2];
    $sqlTitle = $mysqli->query("SELECT text FROM files WHERE fileName = '$value' ");
    $rowTitle = $sqlTitle->fetch_array();
    $title[$x2] = $rowTitle[0];
    $replace2 .= $repeat2[1][$x2];

}


$newText = str_replace($repeat2[0][$x2], $replace2, $newText);
}

echo $newText;
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example to use the `preg_replace_callback` function, like this:

```
<?php

$newText = ' title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg"  title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg"  title2="up_164_hT7PJt6RQZkNEn5.jpg" ';

$newText = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?<=\stitle2=")[^"]*(?=")/',
    function ($match) {
        $sqlTitle = $mysqli->query("SELECT text FROM files WHERE fileName = '{$match[0]}' ");
        $rowTitle = $sqlTitle->fetch_array();
        return $rowTitle[0];
    },
    $newText);

echo $newText;
```

Note that `(?<= ... )` is the lookbehind positive feature and `(?= ... )` is a lookahead positive feature (see links).

References:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php